# How to Remove SIP button of windows mobile

Tags: c#, c++, windows-mobile, sip

How to remove the SIP button of Windows mobile? I need a solution for Windows Mobile V6.
Please post some sample app, or link about how to remove the SIP button.

I have tried out this technique..

SHFullScreen(this.Handle, SHFS_HIDESIPBUTTON);

This is not working for me. If you know please post full code.

Answer (score 2):

If you only want to remove the SIP, this works for me (I'm using CeGCC as my compiler), and no .dll linking is needed (tested on a HTC Universal running WM6.1).

```
HWND hWndSipButton = FindWindow(TEXT("MS_SIPBUTTON"), NULL);
if(hWndSipButton != NULL) {
    ShowWindow(hWndSipButton, SW_HIDE);
}
```

Keep in mind you'll also need to insert this code at places right after windows mobile likes to restore the SIP (e.g. put it in response to a WM_ACTIVATE message too).

Answer (score 1):

If you want the entire display surface for your application, then this should do the trick:

```
iDisplayWidth = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSCREEN);
iDisplayHeight = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSCREEN);
SHFullScreen(hwndClient, SHFS_HIDESIPBUTTON | SHFS_HIDETASKBAR | SHFS_HIDESTARTICON);
MoveWindow(hwndClient, 0, 0, iDisplayWidth, iDisplayHeight, TRUE);
```